# Link to Name in Slide Show

Tags: php, jquery

It's me again - The code is working now, but I can't seem to be able to add a link to the '*$info['name']*' in the *alt*.
 I want to be able to add links to the picture and the name. The picture link works, but the link does not appear in the name.

I may have some mistakes in the code below.
The link works on the picture but now in the alt.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Pager Demo with Prev/Next Controls</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../jq.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="cycle.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#main { margin: 20px }
#nav { margin: 10px; position: relative }
#nav li { float: left; list-style: none}
#nav a { margin: 5px; padding: 3px 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #fc0; text-decoration: none }
#nav li.activeSlide a { background: #faa; color: black }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#slideshow').cycle({
          prev:    '.prev', // Setup prev links
          next:    '.next', // Setup next links
          pager:   '.nav',       // Setup pager navs          
          before: function () {         
          $("#name").html($(this).children("img").attr("alt"));    
      }
     }); 
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#left, #slideshow, #right { float: left; width: 200px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- left nav bar -->
<div id="left">
    <a href="#"><span class="prev">Prev</span></a> 
    <a href="#"><span class="next">Next</span></a>

    <ul class="nav"></ul>
</div>

<!-- slideshow -->
<div id="slideshow">


 <?php
                 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect");
                 mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

                 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people") or die(mysql_error());
                 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){

   <!--THIS CODE BELOW -->
     echo "<a href=\"display.php?id=".$info['id']."\"><img src=\"uploads/".$info['pic'] . "\" alt=\"<b><a href=\"display.php?id=".$info['id']."\">".$info['name']."</a></b><br />".$info['sex']. "<br />".$info['location'].
       "<br />".$info['age']."</a>";
  }
?>

</div>

 <div id="name">

 </div>
 <!-- right nav bar -->
 <div id="right">
     <a href="#"><span class="prev">Prev</span></a> 
     <a href="#"><span class="next">Next</span></a>
     <ul class="nav"></ul>
 </div>


 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate your help folks to be able to add link to the name dynamically.

Comment: Question is not clear, you want the string you are echoing to appear in inside the name div?

Comment: @Ali - Yes, I want the echo string to appear in the name div; and within that echo string, I have dynamically inserted data for which I want displayed. One of which is $info['name']. I want to dynamically create a link for it. But for now, it's not working...the image displays alright, but not the string in the 'name' div.

Answer (score 0):

instead of echo-ing the string, why not read it into a variable and echo the variable inside you html at the appropriate location `<?php echo $myString; ?>` also looks like you are using HTML inside the `alt` attribute. You can't do that. Even if you *can* do that, you are using double quotes inside double quotes, which will end the double quote and break the string.

Try changing your echo command to:

```
echo "<a href=\"display.php?id=".$info['id']."\"><img src=\"uploads/".$info['pic'] . "\" alt=\"<b><a href='display.php?id=".$info['id']."'>".$info['name']."</a></b><br />".$info['sex']. "<br />".$info['location'].
       "<br />".$info['age']."</a>";
```

The only thing Ive changed is the anchor link (i.e. the part below I replace " with '

```
<a href='display.php?id=".$info['id']."'>
```